# How can I force a certain page to be non-SSL on nginx?

Tags: nginx, debian, web-server, web-hosting, website

I'm looking to have a certain page, example.php, redirect to the non-SSL version if it is accessed via SSL. What type of rewrites should I be looking at?

Answer (score 1):

The following code may be used...

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name domainname.com;

  ssl_certificate /path/to/cert.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /path/to/cert.key;

  location = /path/to/example.php {
    return 301 http://$host$request_uri;
  }

  # other directives here
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name domainname.com;

  location = /path/to/example.php {
    # include directives to process PHP here
  }

  # return all other requests to SSL
  location / {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have my SSL and non-SSL server block in one block.

Comment: Is it hard to split / divide it?